# use python subprocess.popen in aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm using a python third-party library that uses `subprocess.popen` to spawn a worker process.

Is it authorized to create a subprocess in aws lambda ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are free to do all sorts of things with the underlying OS. Read more about runing arbitrary executables here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/